# How do I send value from one intent to another using JOVO?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have the following intent structure:

```
async ContactIntent() {
   const contact_id = this.$inputs.contactid.value;
   // Contact detail is fetched from API

   // if this contact is associated with any group
   // ask user whether he wants to know about the groups
   // expected answers could either be YES or NO.
   // if YES, I like to jump to ContactGroupIntent intent with
   // present contact_id
   this.ask('User 19588 is associated with 5 groups. Do you want to know what they are? Say YES or NO.')
},

async ContactGroupIntent() {
   // when called directly
   const contact_id = this.$inputs.contactid.value;
   // or I want to grab the id sent from ContactIntent after user says YES

   // API fetches contact groups and outputs the same

},

'AMAZON.YesIntent': function() {
  // Do I need to do something here?
},

'AMAZON.NoIntent': function() {
},
```

I am using JOVO framework for building the skill.

Question are:

1. How can I pass a value from one intent to another without losing any state
2. Since I cannot use `this.ask()` and `return this.toIntent("intent_name")` simultaneously, how I can navigate user to another intent after alexa outputs something and that too with the value I have in current intent?

**Example:**
**Intent-A** has a value of 19558
The contact with above ID is associated with say 5 different groups.
Is this possible that alexa outputs something like:

> User 19588 is associated with 5 groups. Do you want to know what they
> are?

and expects a `YES` or `NO`.
If YES is the answer alexa moves the control from **Intent-A** to **Intent-B** with 19588, inside Intent-B it does rest of the operations and finally outputs the names of those groups.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

use the session data.

Store the value you want other intent to use. For example:

at the Intent-A store the value 19588 in as part of the session data and also ask a question so the user answers "yes" or "no".

```
this.$session.$data.user_number = 19588
this.$speech = 'User 19588 is associated with 5 groups. Do you want to know what they are?'
this.$reprompt = 'Sorry I could not hear you, Do you want to know what they are?'
this.ask(this.$speech, this.$reprompt)
```

If the user says "Yes" AMAZON.YesIntent will be triggered, so

```
'AMAZON.YesIntent': function() {
    let user_number = this.$session.$data.user_number
    // perform all the appropriate verifications here and do the rest you need to do
},
```

Take a look at [this](https://www.jovo.tech/docs/data#session-data)

Now when you use `this.ask()` the mic will stay opened waiting for user's input so accommodate the `speech` and `reprompt` variables to ask the right question and expect the user to say "Yes" or "No".

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't even need to "save" the data if you're using state.

You can just "access it" by:

```
let person = this.$inputs.*<PARAMETER1>*.value; //Change PARAMETER1 for the name of the parameter used on your model.
```

Here is an example:

```
 numberOneIntent(){
    
    return this.toStateIntent('awesomeState', 'numberTwoIntent');
}
```

I'm assuming you know how to ask/require for parameters using your model on this numberOneIntent

```
awesomeState: {

      numberTwoIntent(){

      let person = this.$inputs.person.value;

      let amount = this.$inputs.amount.value;

      console.log("congrats, you got your data from numberOneIntent");
    
      this.tell("yada yada");

    }
}
```